# How do you organize your files in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, filesystem

I switched from macOS to Ubuntu 20.04, and loved the stack feature available to group your files, is there something similar that makes managing files in Ubuntu any easier?

Any help/ideas are appreciated

Comment: This [Stack Exchange resource](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79514/directory-structure-between-mac-osx-and-linux) might give some useful pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application that I use to help me organize my files called Organize My Files. You can install the application from the snap store https://snapcraft.io/organize-my-files. This is how you install it. First check if you have snap installed on your system. Just go in your terminal and type `snap` and if something comes up you have snap installed. Type `sudo snap install organize-my-files` then you should be good to go.  If you do not have snap installed you can install it at this [link](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-ubuntu).